# How to calculate combinations count for this problem

Tags: combinatorics

I will explain my question using simple example, cause I don't know to descrive it properly.
If we have 2 numbers $\{a,b\}$, by comparing them, we get 3 possible combinations: $$a>b, \hspace{3pt} a<b, \hspace{3pt} a=b$$ For 3 numbers $\{a,b,c\}$ we get, $$b<a>c, \hspace{3pt} b>a<c, \hspace{3pt} a<b>c, \hspace{3pt} a>c<b, \hspace{3pt} \hspace{3pt} a=b=c, \hspace{3pt} a=b>c, \hspace{3pt} etc...$$

How to calculate how many combinations exist for n numbers.

Comment: If we follow your leading example, the one with $3$ numbers is false... We should find : $a<b<c, a<b=c, a<c<b, b<a<c, b<a=c, b<c<a, c<a<b, c<a=b, c<b<a$

Comment: If you call $a$ and $b$ "$2$ numbers" then implicitly you accept that $a\neq b$. If you want to include the possibility that $a=b$ then you must speak of $2$ symbols that both stand for a number (possibly both for the same). Strangely when it comes to $3$ numbers you seem to accept tacitly that the numbers are distinct.

Comment: In your first example : are you aware that $a>b$ and $b<a$ mean the same thing?

Comment: @BusyAnt it was typo, fixed

Comment: What sense do you give to $a<b>c$ ? Is $c$ between $a$ and $b$, lower than both $a$ and $b$ ? Does it have any kind of matter in your example?

Comment: @drhab No I do not accept that they are distinct, just wasn't going to type all combinations, specially for u I did it

Comment: My first critic remains: if e.g. $a=b=c$ then is only $1$ *number* (not $3$) and there are $3$ *symbols*.

Comment: These are the [ordered Bell numbers, aka  Fubini numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) No known closed form.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for answer.Can you post it as an aswer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, these are the [ordered Bell numbers,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) aka the Fubini numbers. Perhaps the cleanest formulation of the problem is that we have $n$ (distinct) runners in a race, and we want to count the number $a(n)$ of possible orders of finish, including ties.

There are useful recurrences, ways to express $a(n)$ as sums,  and asymptotics, but no known closed form.

Answer (score -2):

Put the n numbers in any order. There are $(n-1)$ spaces between the numbers in which you have to put signs. There are 3 signs to choose from for each space. Therefore, the solution is 3^(n-1).

Comment: If we rigourously follow this reasoning, we would find $3^{n-1}$, not $3\times (n-1)$. Furthermore, eventhough this answer is "lexically" correct, it would not make much sens, mathematically speaking.